# SQL Server query problem with top and order by

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I am new to SQL and have a problem with top and order by clause.

There is my data

```
id  name
------------
1   a
2   b
4   ccc
6   aaaaaa
```

and I have query

```
select top 1 
    *
from
    (select top 2 
         *
     from 
         testing2) t
order by 
    id desc
```

The result is

```
id  name
-----------
6   aaaaaa
```

I don't know why it prints out the last record.

Here is my thoughts for the query:

First, I want to fetch the second record from the table. Since it is already sorted by id, I don't need order by in the inner query. So the inner query will return

```
1  a
2  b
```

Then, I use `top 1` and `order by desc` to get the second record.

Obviously I am wrong. I know solution by adding order by in the inner query.

But I want to know why, and the step of running this query in the database.

Comment: `top` without `order by` returns arbitrary rows.  If you have a particular ordering in mind, then you need `order by`.

Comment: *Since it is already sorted by id, I don't need order by* - here's where you're totally wrong - a set of data in a relational database is ***NEVER*** already ordered - you get ordering ***ONLY*** if you explicitly apply an `ORDER BY` when selecting. ....

Comment: still there are cases where you sort on ties @marc_s you still can get a non deterministic ("random") sort even when using `ORDER BY`

Comment: @RaymondNijland: ok - agreed - edge case in my opinion - but *without* an `ORDER BY`, there's definitely no reproducible ordering - that's my main point

Comment: indeed @marc_s without `ORDER BY` the results are always non deterministic ("random") ... But it isn't really a edge case as pagination and or batching always requires a deterministic sorting no exceptions.. Meaning atleast one column in the `ORDER BY` needs to have a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key. or you know for sure that column has unique data..

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I still have some question.....1.when I test the subquery individually .It already print out `a` and `b`. Why would that happen if `top without order by returns arbitrary rows` .....2.`id` is primary key, by default, isn't it a clustered Index which is sorted?? ... 3.does `order by` cause sorting which affect the query performance??

Answer (score 1):

You need the `order by` in the subquery.  Otherwise, the rows are unordered and any rows can be returned:

```
select top 1 *
from (select top 2 *
      from testing2
      order by id asc
     ) t
order by id desc;
```

Of course, `fetch` simplifies this:

```
select t.*
from testing t
order by id asc
offset 1 row fetch first 1 row only;
```